# Is Matrix Direct Sum Distributive over Matrix Addition?

Tags: matrices, direct-sum

Simple question that's been bugging me - is the matrix direct sum in general distributive over matrix addition? ie is the following true?
$\bigoplus_{i=1}^n (A_i+B_i)=(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i) +(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n B_i) $
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of the direct sum using block diagonal matrices. Each block corresponds to a different orthogonal subspace. Implicitly, your matries $A_i$, $B_i$ all belong to the subspace indexed by $i$. In each subspace, you are just doing normal matrix addition. Distributivity means that you don't sum blocks from different subspaces.

Example:

\begin{align}
\bigoplus_{i=1}^2 A_i+\bigoplus_{i=1}^2 B_i
= & 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 & 0\\ 
0 & A_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
+ & 
\begin{bmatrix}
B_1 & 0\\ 
0 & B_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
= & 
\begin{bmatrix}
A_1 +B_1 & 0\\ 
0 & A_2 + B_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
= & 
\bigoplus_{i=1}^2(A_i+B_i)
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for a counter-example earlier but it's clear now why there can't be one. By similar argument do we have:
$\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_iB_i = (\bigoplus_{i=1}^n A_i) (\bigoplus_{i=1}^n B_i)$?

Comment: Yep. It follows for the multiplication formula for block matrices